# How to render Model field in Django, either it contains text or image?

Tags: python, django

In models.py, question field contains text and question_img filed contains image. Questions may be text or image. If question filed contains text, question_img field should be empty and if question_img filed contains image, question filed should be empty. So, how to render text question or image question based on condition? If question field is empty then it should render question_img from Database vice-versa.

models.py:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
        paper = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='None')
        qs_no = models.IntegerField(default=None)
        question = models.TextField(max_length=500)
        question_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True) 
        option_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_b = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_c = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        option_d = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        ans = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py:

```
class QuestionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    paper = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices = PAPER_CHOICES))
    class Meta:
        model=Questions
        fields=[
            'paper',
            'qs_no',
            'question',
            'question_img',
            'option_a',
            'option_b',
            'option_c',
            'option_d',
            'ans',
        ]
```

views.py:

```
def questions(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('questions')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('questions')
        else:
            form = QuestionsForm()
        return render(request, 'questions.html', {'form':form})




def render_questions(request):
    print(f'user in render_questions is {request.user.username}', flush=True)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
       return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        global exam_session
        exam_session = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
        print(f"session id in render ques is {exam_session}", flush=True)
        questions = Questions.objects.all()
        ques = []
        qs_no = 1
        for q in questions:
            que = {}
            que['qs_no'] = qs_no
            qs_no = qs_no + 1
            que['question'] = q.question
            que['id'] = q.id
            que['option_a'] = q.option_a
            que['option_b'] = q.option_b
            que['option_c'] = q.option_c
            que['option_d'] = q.option_d
            ques.append(que)
        print(f"ques: {ques}", flush=True)
        return render(request, 'report.html', {'ques': ques})
```

template.html:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="answer" method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="questionContainer">
            {% for question in ques %}
             <div class="questiondiv" data-questionId="{{ question.id }}">
              <div class="bghead1">
               <h5><strong>Question &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.qs_no }}.</strong></h5>
             </div>
              <div class="font mrl">
                <h5><input type="hidden" class="form-check-input" name="question" value="{{ question.question }}">{{ question.question }}</h5>
              </div>
               <div class="radio pad">
                 <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="question{{question.qs_no}}" value="{{question.option_a}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_a }}</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio pad">
                 <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="question{{question.qs_no}}" value="{{question.option_b}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_b }}</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio pad">
                 <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="question{{question.qs_no}}" value="{{question.option_c}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_c }}</label>
               </div>
               <div class="radio pad">
                <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="question{{question.qs_no}}" value="{{question.option_d}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ question.option_d }}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
           {% endfor %}
        </div>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using template if/else is a straightforward approach.

```
      {% if question.question %}
        <div class="font mrl">
          <h5><input type="hidden" class="form-check-input" name="question" value="{{ question.question }}">{{ question.question }}</h5>
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="font mrl">
          <h5><img src="{{ question.image.url }}"></h5>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
```